# Guarantee that a C program starting at exactly the same time as a Python program will have the same integer time value

Tags: python, c, time

I am currently writing code involving piping data from a C program to a Python program. This requires that they both have exactly the same `time` value as an integer. My method of getting the time is:

- `time(0)` for C
- `int(time.time())` for Python

However, I am getting inconsistencies in output leading me to believe that this is not resulting in the same value. The C program takes < 0.001s to run, while:

```
time ./cprog | python pythonprog.py
```

gives times typically looking like this:

```
    real    0m0.043s
    user    0m0.052s
    sys     0m0.149s
```

Approximately one in every 5 runs results in the expected output. Can I make this more consistent?

Comment: This is a bad idea, as startup time is out of your control. You should pass the value on the command line (or otherwise). Then you can be sure it's the same for both.

Comment: Have a third program that starts both your current programs, passing the time to them as arguments? Otherwise it's not really possible on a modern multitasking system.

Comment: Unless you have a real-time OS, there is no way to ascertain that they run immediately, let alone at "exactly the same time". I'm guessing passing in a reference time to both (via the environment, or as command-line argument), perhaps from a wrapper script, might work better, and hopefully accomplish whatever it is that you hope to actually accomplish. Maybe see also " XY problem".

Comment: Based on the feedback here, I've made the C program output it's start time for the Python script to use.

Comment: I can neither tell what you did, what you expected nor what you observed. Please read [ask]. Consider providiing a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a solution - but an explanation.

When starting python (or other interpreted/VM langauge), there is usually startup cost associated with read and parsing the many modules that are needed. Even a small Python program like 'print 5' will will perform large number of IO.

The startup cost will delay the initial lookup for the current time.

From strace output, invoking a python code will result in >200 open calls, ~ (f)stat, >20 mmap calls, etc.

```
strace -c python prog.py
% time     seconds  usecs/call     calls    errors syscall
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
 31.34    0.000293           1       244       178 openat
  9.84    0.000092           1       100           fstat
  9.20    0.000086           1        90        60 stat
  8.98    0.000084           1        68           rt_sigaction
  7.81    0.000073           1        66           close
  2.14    0.000020           2         9           brk
  1.82    0.000017           9         2           munmap
  1.39    0.000013           1        26           mmap
  1.18    0.000011           2         5           lstat
...
```